# WinUI3 Desktop Navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to port an application that was developed using UWP to WinUI in Desktop using Project Reunion. So far, I updated the app and it compiles fine. But I got an issue understanding how navigation is implemented in WinUI 3, in the UWP app I had a mainshell that contains the whole app navigation system, but In WinUI how could I implement such navigation system. I've looked for samples, but there's very little information available.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found all the answer in the WinUI3 Control Gallery repo.
https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/tree/winui3preview